# Finding pre-processed MODIS products?

Tags: remote-sensing, modis, digital-image-processing, missing-data

I am trying to recognize burnt areas based on some MODIS products and I just realized that I am missing a bunch pixels from the coastline masking. As you can understand that is an issue because I am missing data.

Is there a website/archive where I can find the pre-processed images, or is there a smarter suggestion on how to handle this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please supply a screenshot highlighting the problem you are encountering? What geographic area are you working with?

Comment: See for yourself.

Comment: Where did you download this imagery?

Comment: From USGS' earth-explorer.Now, if I recall correctly top one is Terra and bottom is Aqua.